# Measure file server performance

Tags: windows, performance, benchmarking, server, fileserver

I'm doing a benchmark of my file server (running Serv-U). I'm trying to measure Disk I/O in Windows 7 with the Performance Monitor. I have the server running and a client connected to it. My problem is that when I upload a file from the client to the server while measuring the disk IO in the server I don't see any changes.

The file is successfully transferred but I don't see any activity in the monitor. Am I doing anything wrong? Any other way to measure the performance of a file server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is what I normally use, Win 7 is the same and I run Perfmon on the client and the server. There can be strange results due to caching and deferred writing. So, measure performance for a time after data transfer appears to be finished.

**Setting Up Performance Monitor**

This is arranged via Start, Run or Start Search with Vista, type Perfmon then press Enter - Vista administrative permission required. The program can also be started via Control Panel, Administrative Tools, Performance or Reliability and Performance with Vista. XP - select Performance Logs and Alerts, Counter Logs. Vista - select Data Collection Sets, User Defined. Via menu Action select New Log Settings or New Data Collection Set, XP - type name and OK then Add Counters. Vista - Create Manually, Next, tick Performance Counter, Next, Add.

Performance Object or Counter select and Add - Processor, % Processor Time - PhysicalDisk, Disk Read Bytes/sec, Disk Reads/sec, Disk Write Bytes/sec, Disk Writes/sec - Memory, Page Reads/sec, Page Writes/sec. Close or OK. [For LAN/network measurements add counters from Network Interface - Bytes Received/sec, Bytes Sent/sec, Packets Received/sec, Packets Sent/sec, possibly Output Queue Length, Discard and Error counters].

For other settings see Perfmon Help. Those used/changed were Sample Interval 1 second, log destination, log type Text Comma Delimited (CSV for spreadsheet), manual start/stop, 10000 samples Vista.